# Padding in Autocomplete Text field Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try to set a padding for the text in an autocomplete field.
I did it with a normal Text field like this:

```
 TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
            ),
```

But I'm not able to do something like this on the autocomplete field.

```
class AutocompleteField extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const List<String> _kOptions = <String>[
    'Superdry',
    'H&M',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        }
        return _kOptions.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

The above field is the autocomplete and I want that it looks like the lower image.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Does wrapping the `AutocompleteField` class with a `Padding` widget work? Something like `Padding(child: AutocompleteField(),);`

Comment: That has the effect, that the line under the value has also a padding

Comment: Oh, now I see your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fieldViewBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete/fieldViewBuilder.html) for that.
Something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        }
        return _kOptions.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context, 
                         TextEditingController textEditingController,
                         FocusNode focusNode,
                         VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
          return TextFormField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            onFieldSubmitted: (str) => onFieldSubmitted(),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
            )
          );
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
    );
  }
```